# CSS Preproccessor: Sass, Less, Php & Vals from the database

Tags: php, sass, less

I'm finally delving in to CSS Preprocessing, and trying to figure out the best route to go.  My primary questions are:

1. What is the value of using SASS or LESS over Php?
2. If I were to use SASS or LESS, what's the best way to integrate values from the database?

Obviously using php to print styles in the header is a pretty bad idea.  I was using php to create a stylesheet, and importing it as 'Content-Type: text/css'.  It would then create the stylesheet that would be served as such and cached properly. I could use values from the database and work with the language I'm already adept with.

What advantages do SASS and LESS have over Php for creating/working with the stylesheets, and if I were using them, what is the best way to use values from the database?  Would I need to use Php to grab the values from the database, basically continuing my methods above, only for that use, then using SASS, LESS, or another to work with the rest of the stylesheet?

Thank you very, very much for your help!

Comment: Why do you want to get data from the database to use in your CSS? What data is it?

Comment: you should look at the php port of less.. might make things easier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS preprocessors like SASS and LESS give you much more than just serving a PHP (or any other server side language) file with dynamic code, served with a `content-type:text/css`

They give you:

- **Mixins** – Classes for classes.
- **Parametric mixins** – Classes to which you can pass parameters, like functions.
- **Nested Rules** – Classes within classes, which cut down on repetitive code.
- **Operations** – Math within CSS.
- **Color functions** – Edit your colors.
- **Namespaces** – Groups of styles that can be called by references.
- **Scope** – Make local changes to styles.
- **JavaScript evaluation** – JavaScript expressions evaluated in CSS.

To do all that in PHP by yourself would be a fair effort!

Regarding getting data from a database and using it in your SASS / LESS, it's not something that preprocessors would allow you to do out of the box. You could write your own PHP code that would read from a database, collect the information and values you need, and then write a SASS or LESS file to the filesystem using these values. You could just write a normal CSS file too if you don't need the features above that preprocessors give you.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the thorough answer.  Yes, I'm pretty sure Php can accomplish all that, and there's plenty of classes that do accomplish it.  However, at the moment, I sure don't have the need.  Aside from that, better to use the right language/code for the designed purpose.  
Appreciate it!

Comment: That's the problem, and what I'm getting at.  Sass and LESS are amazing because they've focused on CSS implemenation.  But as far as I can tell, and if they are processed by js/php/ruby, they can never be more powerful than them.  I'm still befuddled as to why, rather the writing the code to interpret the css preporcessor, just make libraries/classes/functions to work with the language itself - js/php/ruby?  There's already classes to work with colors, operations, namespaces, scopes and js evaluation - and are everyday commonplace functionality.  Not to mention they have far more power.

Comment: Php/js naturally integrate with everything else, in case you wanted css to be modified based on referring site, day/time, etc, rather than modifying inline styles or switching entire stylesheets.  Images can be written directly into the css as needed.  Database values worked with. Regex.  If the evaluation was done server side, bypassing LESS/Sass and using just Php/js/ruby would save resources.  Some good articles exemplifying: net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/supercharge-your-css-with-php-under-the-hood colors: barelyfitz.com/projects/csscolor, another: fwebde.com/css/php-dynamic-css

Comment: All that being said, I will admit I'm not interested in learning a new language, syntax highlighting, autocompletion, and learning how to maximize it over time.  I'd rather invest in what has more power in the long run, and if my conclusions have any basis, I'm still wondering why so much is being invested in languages with greater limitations.  But again, I still don't know them inside and out, so I'm hoping someone can fill me in the the difference of their optimal possibilities, not just what they currently provide, and discounting the amazing php/js style resources that do exist.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who uses php quite a bit and has been using Sass for a few months:

1. What is the value of using SASS or LESS over Php?

In these pre-processors, all the work has already been done for you. You could feasibly achieve the same goals using php you wrote yourself, but it would be a waste of time. Months, perhaps even years, of work, testing and evaluation have gone into Sass and Less, to name two. Why duplicate that work?

Many IDE's already support syntax-highlighting for .scss files, for example, making it easier to read and write the code.

You don't need a server to run Sass or Less, making them quite portable. Sass does require Ruby, but Less only requires javascript, ie: it will run anywhere.

Using something like Sass will make you think in a very structured way about your css, and encourage some good habits.

1. If I were to use SASS or LESS, what's the best way to integrate values from the database?

I've never done anything like that, but here's how I might approach it.
Have a table in the database dedicated to storing the variables, start off with just an id, a class-name, and a value stored as a text string, be it a measurement, a hex colour, whatever you need.

Whenever you add a new definition to the table, have a script run which updates a .scss file (if you're using Sass), called something like db_values.scss Simply write in text which lists a big bunch of variables and their values, in the syntax required by the preprocessor.

In your main pre-processor file, import this generated file, it won't give you bloated style-sheets, the resulting css will only use the variables it needs.

Comment: From the database, you're saying grab the values with Php or another to write to the scss file, right? Indeed, I'll probably stick with LESS. As for now, I still need to grab user defined styles from the database, so the slightest bit if Php will do for now. Looking forward to delving into it.  Thanks!